# Generate random word from two known words

Tags: php

I can do this with numbers:

```
<?=number_format(mt_rand(0,1));?>
```

What I want to do is, instead of 0 or 1, echo the words **firstclass** or **secondclass**.

This is because I cannot use numbers as class identifiers in CSS.

Essentially, this is just for displaying random stuff within a list and prepending the class identifier with either firstclass or secondclass.

```
.firstclass {display:none;}
```

I am not ace with PHP, so I guess I need to set up an array, and somehow attribute:

0 = firstclass
1 = secondclass

within the array, so that I can get my little test script working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to obtain some integer in [0,9] just multiply with 10^n, and after calculate modulo 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [ternary-style if statement](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) if you only have two possibilities:

```
<?=(mt_rand(0,1) == 0) ? 'firstclass' : 'secondclass'?>
```

Comment: It's recommended not to use short tags since they only exist for backwards compatibility. They're deprecated.

Comment: @ArtaexMedia: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use.  While the short tags `<%` and `<?` may be deprecated (because they conflict with XML templating engines), `<?=` most certainly is not.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php echo (mt_rand(0,1) == 0 ? 'firstclass' : 'secondclass'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this? :

```
$words = array('firstclass', 'secondclass');
$randomWord = $words[mt_rand(0,1)];
```

Answer (score 3):

Or...

```
class="a-prefix-<?=number_format(mt_rand(0,1));?>"
```

CSS classes have to start with an underscore, a dash, or a letter but you can have numbers after that.

Comment: I didnt know that, good concept. Added that to my toolset :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you going to say that `0 = firstclass`, `1 = secondclass` why not just use [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) like this:

```
$classes = array(
    'firstclass',
    'secondclass'
);

$randClass = $classes[array_rand($classes)];

echo $randClass;
```

This will also give you the possibility to add more classes if you ever needed

Comment: I think thats cleaner, for other stuff. Much cleaner and more manageable. That is kind of what I was expecting, but didnt know how to do. Thankyou @Steven Farley